# How to correctly infer React props from as prop with generic overload

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I'm trying to make generic component that can infer its prop types from `as` prop.

I found that following typing works OK for `{ as?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements }`:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Comp<TComponentProps extends {}> {
  (props: TComponentProps & { as?: undefined }): React.ReactElement | null;

  <
    TProps extends { as: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements },
    P = TProps extends { as: infer C }
      ? C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
        ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[C] & TComponentProps
        : TComponentProps
      : TComponentProps
  >(
    props: TProps & P,
  ): React.ReactElement | null;
}

declare const A: Comp<{}>;
declare const B: Comp<{ test: boolean }>;
declare const C: React.FunctionComponent<{ fn: boolean }>;
declare const D: React.ComponentClass<{ cls: boolean }>;

<A />; // valid
<B />; // invalid, test is missing
<B test />; // valid
<A as="img" src={10} />; // invalid, src cannot be a number
<A as="img" src="" />; // valid
/* 

<A as={B} />; // invalid, test is missing
<A as={B} test />; // valid
<A as={C} />; // invalid, fn is missing
<A as={C} fn />; // valid
<A as={D} />; // invalid, cls is missing
<A as={D} cls />; // valid

*/
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/en/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4BhXMAHgBUPwItJPQAKOMAGc4SAB4NaAEykBvAL4A%20OMqpw4ACjDiJALjh9Og4TDERJcAGRa4KCQH5TAV0VJMdJArhVAEpTZHQYADowjABRABskECs4AB84Wg84uIpqSl0uHV0zGztZeSUnF1MAayQATwhMOAApAGUADQiASXooOglgNHjEqylVABpC3RE4AF5io2k5YQrlZxM4OkxGdkCpotddspWpWoamts6emD7aAaGEpPoJfaK4Q8vu3v7B4aeYCQAbTYAF0HGZ%20JAhKIjK8iqZzAJodZYXk3nAEZDLDDbC80eo9PtDLiESUpI4RJM0SFEMRItEYH9kmkMlkcqoqFQFEg0HEUEQ4GhBBJ4ABBUyQrhqdQ5bm8-msIV3eAAIQlnClcAYItMACMIBAEihaIEZVyeXyBUqRexQnSIgAxLwYYCCLHIzWYWh6g1Gk0aWUWhWC4XwAAidvCEXdVjYfIkEk1vI2%20sNqH9ZtyXFFcAA9DK87m4AA3FBxYAKKhcFV5gu5ot0UvlhTjLVIG3AKQgTsDWgAcyrNe18HzpELJbLFarOZcswARKA%203O4BIoGhZsoAIwABlUtbH9c2tCbFdbq7QguNtAg8F1rBQ6Q8IDvUGn63ni%20X5-ny9H45PlaULmABUcCcpQ2bvsoKp7n%20h6NpOLZth2XY9nQA4QTOEgbjByEjnWRYAW%20s7KGwsEEUeAGtl6myoQm6HEdhpF7jRcGEYhjEbmG5EHg2x6Ia2ya0XA3b0f2nHKNxgpxFIbETs24HAbmQA)

This one works OK but when I want to achieve the same thing but with added support for `FunctionalComponent` and `ComponentClass` with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Comp<TComponentProps extends {}> {
  (props: TComponentProps & { as?: undefined }): React.ReactElement | null;

  <
    TProps extends { as: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements },
    P = TProps extends { as: infer C }
      ? C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
        ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[C] & TComponentProps
        : TComponentProps
      : TComponentProps
  >(
    props: TProps & P,
  ): React.ReactElement | null;

  <
    TProps extends { as: React.JSXElementConstructor<any> },
    P = TProps extends { as: React.JSXElementConstructor<infer CProps> }
      ? CProps & TComponentProps
      : TComponentProps
  >(
    props: TProps & P,
  ): React.ReactElement | null;
}

declare const A: Comp<{}>;
declare const B: Comp<{ test: boolean }>;
declare const C: React.FunctionComponent<{ fn: boolean }>;
declare const D: React.ComponentClass<{ cls: boolean }>;

<A />; // valid
<B />; // invalid, test is missing
<B test />; // valid
<A as="img" src={10} />; // invalid, src cannot be a number
<A as="img" src="" />; // valid
<A as={B} />; // invalid, test is missing
<A as={B} test />; // valid
<A as={C} />; // invalid, fn is missing
<A as={C} fn />; // valid
<A as={D} />; // invalid, cls is missing
<A as={D} cls />; // valid
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/en/play?#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-v+CjjM2SC5sAUggIhAy0AA5kBIEtvA76kJ+P5-gBQEvi4swAESgGhZFwBIUBoLMygAIwAAyqKBeHgZstBQQBsG0WgWbyrQEDwG2rAoLGIBiVAxHrORlHUfx5HUbh+E8YBT4kRIDG1mxqmcZBhEwXBCFIShdAYZpcnKLpJk4WBX7qbJpHKGwekOVx6mwYumxmeeFnOdprlsT5+mOUZgUMbu7kcRB3FGbBV6+XAyH+ehkXKNFWZxFIYUEdBQA)

I don't get the expected results but all lines pass through typecheck.

I tried multiple possible solutions for example:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Comp<TComponentProps extends {}> {
  <
    TProps extends {
      as?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
    },
    P = TProps extends { as?: infer C }
      ? C extends undefined | unknown
        ? {}
        : C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
        ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[C]
        : {}
      : {}
  >(
    props: TProps & TComponentProps & P,
  ): React.ReactElement | null;
  <
    TProps extends {
      as?: React.JSXElementConstructor<any>;
    },
    P = TProps extends { as: React.JSXElementConstructor<infer P> } ? P : {}
  >(
    props: TProps & TComponentProps & P,
  ): React.ReactElement | null;
}

declare const A: Comp<{}>;
declare const B: Comp<{ test: boolean }>;
declare const C: React.FunctionComponent<{ fn: boolean }>;
declare const D: React.ComponentClass<{ cls: boolean }>;

<A />; // valid
<B />; // invalid, test is missing
<B test />; // valid
<A as="img" src={10} />; // invalid, src cannot be a number
<A as="img" src="" />; // valid
<A as={B} />; // invalid, test is missing
<A as={B} test />; // valid
<A as={C} />; // invalid, fn is missing
<A as={C} fn />; // valid
<A as={D} />; // invalid, cls is missing
<A as={D} cls />; // valid
```

[TypeScript: Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/en/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4BhXMAHgBUPwItJPQAKOMAGc4SAB4NaAEykBvAL4A+OMqpw4XHbrg8xESdLnClWg4bgoJAfgBccANZIAnhExwAUgGUADQA6AEl6KDoJYDQAUQAbJBBhGAkKSltVABobOBE4AF4jEzNZeStlO0cXOkxGdjhVXN0HBrLLKQBXRSRMOiQFOAAfOG7XWggAd1pmw1a1Wd0XNnNyqXcvHwCQ8JhI2mi4xOT6CUW4Vu2wiKiYhKSUiQBtNgBdc5cFjNs4T6bv9QAClyYHEEhcxjBcAAZEZ+JAhKIobCRDlvgBKFzIdAwYLYjD3E7wEa0TrxeLpXT6b66SGmKTtRQqWb2ZyIYi47aElIcA57ToYaBcFC0DzqSmGbK5fJFOmlCxMrRVLEc4Jc448wQSfmCqBcWr1ESaVQXPK-LT-XRAkFgiElKSwvicQQpe0wvJo3SY9k4vEc7n0YZwUnk9L-KgKJBoeIoIhwNBa+AAQWWnC4anFEajMbjCb5cAAQqnwOm4AxtS4AEYQCCJEWNTOUSPR2OsPPa9gq30AMW6GGAgnhLvopcwtCrNbrtAb6WbObbibgABEuxhgkPETA2DGJBJS9HwXBq7XUNONOkqFwk3AAPTi283uAANxQ8WACkvBdv95vj7oL7fBQsjLJAO2AKQQHA6JaAAc0-ECOzvUgH2fV930va97AKAAiUAYOwuAJCgNACmUABGAAGE0kJQ-80KAwjiPjEUJngStWBQYNOhAdioAwqocLwgiiJI7CCJo39UMA-isOUAtqJ-P9aAA99gPLeBwLgSDdzoODKCvAS5JNdTv2QySVI-fTMIkUi2AUsylIs4CxzgTTtOgvSDNkuy4BciTHwsmSbOUJd7No5T6OAg9XIgqDdKC0jQvjeIpH8qT3yAA)

But with no luck. Could anyone please point me to a right direction with the typings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved this with the following typing:

```
type HTMLELProps<
  TElement extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements,
  TComponentProps extends {}
> = { as: TElement } & JSX.IntrinsicElements[TElement] &
  TComponentProps &
  StyleProps &
  React.RefAttributes<any>;


export interface Component<TComponentProps extends {}> {
  displayName?: string;

  // as component (as component type)
  <P>(
    props: { as: React.ComponentType<P> } & P &
      TComponentProps &
      StyleProps &
      React.RefAttributes<any>,
  ): React.ReactElement | null;

  // HTML (as="a")
  (props: HTMLELProps<'a', TComponentProps>): React.ReactElement | null;
  (props: HTMLELProps<'abbr', TComponentProps>): React.ReactElement | null;
  // ... rest 

  // without as prop
  (props: TComponentProps & StyleProps): React.ReactElement | null;
}
```

Basically the problem was that it was hard for typescript to infer props based on generic constraints. Now it works correctly even with autocomplete in Visual Studio Code. The problem is that the types are now a little bit slower. I don't know why, I'd appreciate any help with that.